# Auto screen rotate is enabled when Appium is run in Android

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

I have set auto screen rotate to OFF in my android device. But when I run Appium automation, it gets set to ON somehow. Is there a way to prevent Appium from setting auto screen rotate to ON?

Answer (score 0):

By default Appium should not affect your device rotation in any case: what is set on your device will be used during test execution.

However appium supports command to change screen rotation when you want it, e.g. [java-client](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/a41dca1fd5737261b06801e1c265c03ff5960a95/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriverTest.java)):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.ScreenOrientation;

private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
...
driver.rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
assertEquals(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, driver.getOrientation());
```

**UIAutomator2** adds more flexibility with [rotation change](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/a41dca1fd5737261b06801e1c265c03ff5960a95/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/UIAutomator2Test.java).

Comment: Thanks. But in my case, the rotation is set to Portrait, but at some point of running automation, it gets set to auto-rotation.
I'm using UIAutomator2 and Appium 1.7.1

Comment: If you know the exact point where it happens, try to set rotation to Portrait and see if it helps to stabilize your tests. In the meantime, you can add appium logs and create ticket in https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-server/issues